# Como carregar dados do SQL Server em uma combobox no Android Studio usando Volley?

Tags: php, sql-server, android-studio, volley, spinners

Atualmente, para fins de teste, estou usando uma spinner, mas quero agora implementar os dados que vêm do BD. É possível colocar nesta mesma spinner ou devo criar outra aplicação? Realmente não sei como começar, ou o que utilizar. (Obs: Sou iniciante no Android e estou usando Volley + connector PHP em todas requisições de banco). Criei por um manual da internet, uma spinner e uma classe, só que não estou obtendo resposta. Retorna vazio na spinner.

**busca_torneios.php**

```
    <?php

    $serverName = "server"; 
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( !$conn ) {
        echo "Não conectou";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


    $sql = "SELECT nomeTorneio FROM Torneios";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        echo "sem conexao, sem dados\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }


    $json = array();
    do {
         while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $json[] = $row;
         }
    } while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );
        echo json_encode($json);
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
        sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

**PartidaConfiguracao.class**

```
public class PartidaConfiguracao extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner;
    String URL = "http://localhost/busca_torneios.php";
    ArrayList<String> CountryName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_partida_configuracao);
        CountryName=new ArrayList<>();
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerTorneio);
        loadSpinnerData(URL);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String country=   spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),country,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // DO Nothing here
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if(jsonObject.getInt("success")==1){
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("torneios");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String country=jsonObject1.getString("nomeTorneio");
                        }
                    }
                    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(PartidaConfiguracao.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CountryName));
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**Resultado no browser:**

{"torneios":[{"nomeTorneio":"Brasileirao"},{"nomeTorneio":"Copa Do Brasil "},{"nomeTorneio":"Gauchao "},{"nomeTorneio":"Eurocopa"},{"nomeTorneio":"Campeonato Da Paraiba"},{"nomeTorneio":"Campeonato Teste "}]}

Comment: É possível, mas o ArrayAdapter tem que conter a lista que foi gerada após a consulta com o banco. Do modo que está ai sua pergunta fica muito ampla pois há várias formas de fazer isso.

Comment: Ou seja, primeiro você se conecta ao servidor com o Volley... Gera a lista que será usada... Depois você insere a lista no ArrayAdapter... E depois você insere o array no spinner.

Comment: Entendi. Do banco para um array adapter, e deste para popular o spinner. Vou tentar isso e dou um retorno em breve. Obrigado até aqui.

Comment: Andrei, tentei uns 3 modos diferentes, porem sem sucesso. Poderia dar uma olhada no código novo que fiz?

Comment: Vou ver com calma mais tarde.

Comment: Andrei, tentei algumas vezes como você sugeriu, com dados parseados do Json jogando num array, que entra no adapter, que popula o spinner. Veja abaixo a resposta final segundo solução que você apresentou. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue solução, conforme o Andrei propôs. Obrigado.

```
Aqui popula o spinner com dados do banco.

private void loadSpinnerData(String urlSpin) {
    final ArrayList<String> listaTorneios = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlSpin, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("torneios");
                listaTorneios.add("Selecione o torneio:");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    idTorneio = jsonObject1.getInt("ID_torneio");
                    String nomeTorneio = jsonObject1.getString("nomeTorneio");
                    String var = String.valueOf(idTorneio);
                    listaTorneios.add(var+" "+nomeTorneio);
                }
                spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AcoesFutsal.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaTorneios));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Aqui mostra o spinner:

```
loadSpinnerData(URLsp);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String torneio = spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

E aqui pega o item selecionado no spinner

```
final String stIDnomeTorneio = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: muito bom! Parabéns!

Comment: Coloque-a como correta!

Comment: Comentários só consigo colocar como úteis, não como corretos. Só consigo colocar "correto" para respostas. Responda com qualquer observação que eu voto ali. Obrigado!

Comment: Não Paulo! Coloque a SUA RESPOSTA como correta!

Comment: Ok, Andrei. Não tinha entendido. Pronto.